# Juniper Bot in Discord

Tags: discord, discord.js, helper

I recently made a server in discord for my friends. I want to create an anonymous chat using the Juniper bot. This means that when someone writes a message to a certain chat, it will be sent to the server on behalf of the bot. I saw this idea from a YouTuber on his ds channel and I want to implement it at home. Please help anyone who understands.
attached an example of how it should look like[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73BIL.png)
here is the server of this YouTuber for an example of what it should look like:https://discord.gg/qNC3DNKw (there's an anonymous chat)

I have tried to do this, but my skills are not capable of solving such a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify and use a bot to send messages (if that's what you mean), you can use the Slash command .like /say < message > < channel >